# How to rollup similar rows in UITableView like iOS Phone Recents using Core Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

What is the best way to rollup similar rows in UITableView like the Phone's Recents tab. I'm using Core Data and currently displaying data chronologically based on a "timestamp" field in my NSManagedObject. The iPhone Recents table groups like rows into one row to compress redundant data.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

[image: rollup similar rows]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that Apple has some easier way they do it in their code, but here is what I came up with.  There is 1 `NSArray` (with some raw data) that I instantiate in the `viewDidLoad` method, and then 2 `NSMutableArray`'s that are declared as properties (and lazily instantiated) in the .h file.  Here is my code.

.h

```
@interface RollUpTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *rollUpTableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *names;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *countOfNames;

@end
```

.m

```
-(NSMutableArray *)names{
    if(!_names) _names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return _names;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)countOfNames{
    if (!_countOfNames) _countOfNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _countOfNames;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *rawData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Jack", @"Jill", @"Jill", @"Ryan", @"Bill", @"Ryan", @"Ryan", @"Ryan", @"Steve", @"Katie", @"Jill", @"Ryan", @"Ryan", nil];

    int countOfLikeNames = 0;
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < [rawData count]; i++){
        if (i == 0) {
            //Putting the first name in the names NSMutableArray no matter what
            [self.names addObject:[rawData objectAtIndex:i]];
            countOfLikeNames = countOfLikeNames + 1;
        } else {
            //Checking if the current name is the same as the previous
            if ([rawData objectAtIndex:i] == [rawData objectAtIndex:(i-1)]) { 
                countOfLikeNames = countOfLikeNames + 1;
            } else {
                //Once it runs into a difference in names, add the final count to the countOfNames NSMutableArray
                [self.countOfNames addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:countOfLikeNames]];
                //Starting the count over
                countOfLikeNames = 1;
                //Adding the next name
                [self.names addObject:[rawData objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
        //if the for loop is on its last iteration, add what will be the last object for countOfNames
        if (i == ([rawData count] - 1)) {
            [self.countOfNames addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:countOfLikeNames]];
        }

    }

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.names count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.countOfNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

I was a bit lazy and just used Apple's built in 'Right Detail' style on the UITableViewCell and this is what resulted from the raw data.

[image: rollUpTableView results]

You would have to compare the time stamps that you have from your CoreData, but hopefully this helps you with the concept.

Comment: I was looking for a solution with CoreData, perhaps using some form of aggregation or key path, to roll up the similar data. But like your solution, I ended up modeling the NSManagedEntity with a self-referential relationship of the designated "root" parent of several grouped objects. Thus, the "root" has an NSSet reference to similar objects, and thus has the count. The UITableViewController uses NSFetchedResultsController with a query that limits only to where the "root" property is NULL, only getting the parents. Upon insert, I detect whether to add to a similar "root" or start a new "root"